# Access SQL Query: Find the most recent date entry for each employee for each training course

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im sure this is pretty simple to do but im a complete novice at access especially SQL, basically I work for a safety company and i need to create a query which brings up only the most recent training for each course for each employee.

I have a table in access which looks like this:

> Employee ID... Course ID....Course Date....Valid To date 
>   
>  ....12......................2.................01/02/2013.....01/02/2014
>   
>  ....13......................1.................20/09/2012.....20/09/2012
>   
>  ....12......................2.................01/02/2012.....01/02/2013
>   
>  ....12......................3.................15/06/2013.....15/06/2014
>   
>  ....13......................2.................15/06/2013.....15/06/2014
>   
>  ....13......................1.................19/09/2011.....19/09/2012

*(Sorry about the fullstops im not great at HTML either)* 

What id like to achive is a list of only the most recent of each training per employee, so something that will look like this:

> > Employee ID... Course ID....Course Date....Valid To date 
> >     
> >  ....12......................2.................01/02/2013.....01/02/2014
> >     
> >  ....13......................1.................20/09/2012.....20/09/2012
> >     
> >  ....12......................3.................15/06/2013.....15/06/2014
> >     
> >  ....13......................2.................15/06/2013.....15/06/2014

Theres about 10,000 records on my table so it would help a hell of a lot if I could get some help, ive been trying to solve this for weeks now!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should return the result you desire:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM 
    Training t1 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT [Employee ID], [Course ID], MAX([Course Date]) AS MaxDate 
        FROM Training 
        GROUP BY [Employee ID], [Course ID]
    ) t2 
        ON t1.[Employee ID]=t2.[Employee ID] 
            AND t1.[Course ID]=t2.[Course ID] 
            AND t1.[Course Date]=t2.MaxDate
```

Comment: This solution produces a non-updatable dataset (at least with the recent versions of Access), so if that is an issue, @user2407364 answer is much better

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from t1 as tt where course_date in 
(select max(course_date) from t1 where employeeid==tt.employeeid and 
 courseid = tt.courseid);
```

Instead you could have used row_number, but ms-access doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: THIS is the best answer for me since the output dataset is updatable