# Access SQL Query: Find the most recent date entry for each player's test date with 2 joined tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 1 table and 1 query that are joined by Player ID. I want to show only the latest test date result for height and weight columns in tblPlayerLogistics and Player Name and PlayerID from qryPlayersExtended

PlayerID is located in both table and query and they are joined. 
I have playerID, height, weight,and testdate in tblplayerlogistics
I have PlayerID, Player Name in qryPlayersExtended

I would like a query that returns only one player record labeling the playerId and player name with the most current height and weight of each player determined by the testdate.

Query name: qryPlayersExtended
Table Name: tblPlayerLogistics

I have attached what I am trying to do in an image.  This is an example of one player but I will have multiple players with multiple test dates

I have been struggling with this for weeks any help would be appreciated.  I looked at this previous post but still couldnt figure it out
[similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164299/access-sql-query-find-the-most-recent-date-entry-for-each-employee-for-each-tra)

Comment: SELECT qryPlayersExtended.PlayerID, qryPlayersExtended.[Player Name], tblPlayerLogistics.TestDate, tblPlayerLogistics.Height, tblPlayerLogistics.Weight, tblPlayerLogistics.Scholarship, tblPlayerLogistics.Season, tblPlayerLogistics.AcademicYear
FROM qryPlayersExtended INNER JOIN tblPlayerLogistics ON qryPlayersExtended.PlayerID = tblPlayerLogistics.PlayerID;

Comment: my guess is I need a GROUP BY and an INNER JOIN somewhere just not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is not more than one test for a player on any one date. Warning, air code. Create a new query qryLastTestDate: 
`SELECT PlayerID, Max(TestDate) as LastTestDate FROM tblplayerlogistics Group By PlayerID` Create a second query qryLastTest: 
`SELECT tblplayerlogistics.PlayerID, tblplayerlogistics.TestDate, tblplayerlogistics.height, tblplayerlogistics.weight FROM tblplayerlogistics INNER JOIN qryLastTestDate ON tblplayerlogistics.PlayerID = qryLastTestDate.PlayerID and tblplayerlogistics.TestDate = qryLastTestDate.LastTestDate`
 Your final query would be: 
`SELECT qryPlayersExtended.PlayerID, qryPlayersExtended.[Player Name], qryLastTest.TestDate, qryLastTest.Height, qryLastTest.Weight FROM qryPlayersExtended INNER JOIN qryLastTest ON qryPlayersExtended.PlayerID = qryLastTest.PlayerID;` Add in additional fields as needed.

Answer (score 0):

**You will need two queries for this.**

**First**, you need a query which gets the latest date per player. It will have two columns: PlayerId and Max(TestDate), Grouped by PlayerId. I've named this qryMaxPlayerTestDates. It will look something like this:

```
SELECT PlayerId, Max(TestDate) AS MaxDate
FROM tblPlayerLogistics
GROUP BY PlayerId;
```

**Second**, you join the PlayerId and Dates (MaxDate/TestDate) to get results limited by Max(TestDate). It will look something like this:

```
SELECT tblPlayerLogistics.PlayerId, tblPlayerLogistics.Height, 
tblPlayerLogistics.Weight, tblPlayerLogistics.TestDate, 
qryPlayersExtended.PlayerName
FROM qryPlayersExtended INNER JOIN (qryMaxPlayerTestDates 
INNER JOIN tblPlayerLogistics 
ON (qryMaxPlayerTestDates.MaxDate = tblPlayerLogistics.TestDate) 
AND (qryMaxPlayerTestDates.PlayerId = tblPlayerLogistics.PlayerId)) 
ON qryPlayersExtended.PlayerId = qryMaxPlayerTestDates.PlayerId;
```

If your dates are not duplicated per Player (No Players have more than one test per date, or two tests on same date have different times), you will get one row per Player in the result with the Height/Weight for the latest test date.