# SQL incorrect syntax for displaying most recent review for each client?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm extremely new to SQL, so I don't really know what I'm doing!

I would like a query to display the most recent review taken by each client, so after research; I found the following question:

[Access SQL Query: Find the most recent date entry for each employee for each training course](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164299/access-sql-query-find-the-most-recent-date-entry-for-each-employee-for-each-tra)

I then modified the answer to fit my scenario, by naming my tables and fields - giving me this:

```
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM 
        Clients t1, Reviews t2 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT Reviews.[Review ID], Clients.[Client ID], Clients.[Title], Clients.[First name], Clients.[Surname, MAX(Reviews.[Review date]) AS MaxDate 
            **FROM** Reviews, Clients
            GROUP BY Reviews.[Review ID], Clients.[Client ID]
        ) t3
            ON t1.[Client ID]=t3.[Client ID] 
            AND t2.[Review ID]=t3.[Review ID] 
            AND t2.[Review date]=t3.MaxDate
```

But when I run it, I get a syntax error in the FROM clause. I have bolded the clause. 
For my query, I want this displayed:

```
Review ID....Client ID....Title....First name....Surname....Review date
1            1            Mr       Gerry         Parker     05/10/2015
3            2            Mrs      Georgina      Phillips   22/04/2016
```

When actually an older review by Georgina Phillips exists, the query should only display the newest or most recent review for all clients. I just need review dates to show, not the actual review data.

Each client can have multiple reviews, but each review can have only one client.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception or error, post the line it occurred on and the details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Your query syntax is incorrect, Use this, SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM 
        Clients t1  
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT Reviews.[Review ID], Clients.[Client ID], Clients.[Title], Clients.[First name], Clients.[Surname, MAX(Reviews.[Review date]) AS MaxDate 
            FROM Reviews, Clients
            GROUP BY Reviews.[Review ID], Clients.[Client ID]
        ) t3 ON t1.[Client ID]=t3.[Client ID] INNER JOIN Reviews t2            
            ON t2.[Review ID]=t3.[Review ID] 
            AND t2.[Review date]=t3.MaxDate

Comment: Thanks guys, learningNew - an error still ocurred on the second FROM with your code... Mr. Llama, I have now elaborated - sorry for that!

Comment: Generally speaking, don't use the 'commas in the FROM list' notation; only use the explicit JOIN notation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
SELECT c.*, r.*
FROM Clients as c INNER JOIN
     Reviews as r
     ON c.[Client Id] = r.[Client Id]
WHERE r.[Review Date] = (SELECT MAX(r2.[Review Date])
                         FROM Reviews as r2
                         WHERE r2.[Client Id] = r.[Client Id]
                        );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly @Gordon Linoff

Comment: I posted too early, sorry! Your code is great, but it does not show the most recent date. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @FGibbons . . . As I read the query, it gets the most recent date for each client.  Why do you think it does something else?