# How can I correct this code to be able to get a difference in weights for each client?

Tags: ms-access

I am working in MS Access. My end goal is a database report that shows the total amount lost so far for each client, based on the texts they send in daily. I've been able to extract the number from the message, but I need to be able to have a running report each day with how much they've lost since they first texted in.  I tried this solution with no success: [Access SQL Query: Find the most recent date entry for each employee for each training course](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164299/access-sql-query-find-the-most-recent-date-entry-for-each-employee-for-each-tra)

After that, I'v been working with the code from here: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/weight.php.  I've tried to write a query that brings up the Last Visit Date, but I keep getting type mismatches with this:

DMax("LogDate","NumberQ","TargetFK=" & TargetFK)

NumberQ is a query, where columns are TargetFK (Short text), FirstName (Short text), LastName (short text), LogDate (Date), Message (short text), and Weight (calculated field).

My question is, what am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since TargetFK is a text field, you need quotations around it:

```
 DMax("LogDate","NumberQ","TargetFK='" & [TargetFK] & "'")
```